# Identify resistor on Daewoo AVS1339 speaker

Tags: resistors, audio, identification

[image: failed resistor]

I have a Daewoo AVS1339 200 W barrel speaker. It failed the other day and no power is getting to the display.

After some testing with a multimeter and visual inspection I found a resistor with scorch marks and a cracked ceramic coating.

I am trying to replace the resistor but can't identify what I need. It's a basic grey resistor with one visible black band at the top. Length is about 14 mm, width is 4 mm. The input voltage for the speaker is 15 V. Attached is a picture of the failed resistor. Any ideas what type this might be?

Comment: It is charred beyond recognition what it was. No colour bands visible, as even the remaining ones are burnt. Also, resistors don't simply burn up like that themselves. There is (or was) a fault in the circuit and too much current passed that resistor. If you have not removed or fixed the fault condition, any new resistor will also burn up in identical fashion, if the problem why it burns resistors is not fixed.

Comment: is it measuring open circuit?

Comment: This was supplied by the manufacturer. The ceramic was cracked and there was signing of charring on the resistor and near the circuit board. Beyond th black band and a partial gold band there is nothing.   At the moment, I'm trying trying to get the speaker working and will look for other faults. I can't get any reading off the current resistor to know what I am looking to buy.

Comment: Ask for the manual https://help.daewooelectricals.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360016080559-I-need-an-instruction-manual

Comment: Thanks. I have been working that route as well with Daewoo. No response yet.

Comment: After a bit more reading on some other threads my resistor looks like a fusable resistor... designed to fail. I presume it's designed to protect to the lower voltage components for the screen and controls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So as far as identifying the resistor here is what I think this might be. I'm guessing a metal oxide flameproof fusable resistor. Given the size it matches to 1w resistor. So the last remaining item is the ohms? Or am I well off the mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resistor identified. It a 10ohm 3 watt fusable resistor. I identified the wattage based on the dimensions.  It took a bit of trial and error getting the right resistance but did some guesswork based on input voltage and found a safe starting number and worked my way down till something worked. Crude but effective. I was able to get a resistance reading off the burnt resistor by touching the exposed core to a wire end. That also read 10ohms but I wasn't sure I could trust that reading initially.